# Salesforce Mobile SDK Authentication flow issue

Tags: mobile, authentication, mobilesdk, refresh-token

- Created an android_hybrid Mobile app with Mobile SKD version 2.1
- Added the `remoteAccessConsumerKey` at bootconfig.json as per my
- Connected App Update the oauthscope as `"oauthScopes": ["api refresh_token"]`
- Ran it and connected successfully
- **Kept aside for around 3-4 hours so that app gets idle**
- **Can't access salesforce**

Below is my bootconfig.json

```
{
    "remoteAccessConsumerKey": "my_Consumer_Key",
    "oauthRedirectURI": "sfdc://success",
    "oauthScopes": ["api refresh_token"],
    "isLocal": true,
    "startPage": "index.html",
    "errorPage": "error.html",
    "shouldAuthenticate": true,
    "attemptOfflineLoad": false,
    "androidPushNotificationClientId": ""
}
```

Is there anything to do additionally for `refresh_token` get works which I have missed? I found several related posts on SFSE but none of them answering mine.
If the user keeping as logged in is up to the developer but not handle by the SDK please can someone point where to look at and how to come up with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an bug in v2.1 in the line 336 `forcetkRefresh` of cordova.force.js, it's calling wrong `error` function. It should be `fail` instead of `error`. This has been fixed in v2.2

Answer (score 0):

Seems silly, but check the settings for the mobile app in the org itself. I'm not sure if something got changed with a release (seems unlikely) but I was testing some code recently that hadn't been used in a while, and the refresh kept failing saying the token was invalid. Turns out the refresh token settings had been set to a one-time-use only hence the one I had stored wasn't working.

Comment: As far as I know I checked that as well @LaceySnr. It's `Refresh Token Policy: Refresh token is valid until revoked` in my case. What is the SDK version you have used?